# Discord.js - bot.guilds.get is not a function?

Tags: discord.js

I made a discord bot in discord.js about a year ago and wanted to do some new things with it today, so I went back to it. It worked fine before for a long time, but now on the line `server = bot.guilds.get(serverID);` is gives me the error 'bot.guilds.get is not a function' when it should be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting the error because you're using Discord.js V12 and your bot was made for Discord.js V11.

The solution to this problem is to use:

```js
bot.guilds.cache.get("GuildID")
```

instead of:

```js
bot.guilds.get("GuildID")
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache

Comment: That worked, thanks. I have another similar issue though.  I also added .cache to  `welcomeChannel = server.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelID);` and  `welcomeChannel.fetchMessage(roleComment)` gives me the same error, but when I add the .cache it is undefined

Comment: [The correct usage is:](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) `welcomeChannel.messages.fetch("MessageID")`.

Comment: Do you know why `'client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => {` is triggering when the bot reacts but not when I react?